# Use smaller than on like clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some number like

```
12000
13093
14013
14111
15543
16883
17932
18920
19903
20390
```

These numbers are only an example I have a lot of 14... a lot of 15... etc.

Now in `WHERE` clause of a stored procedure, I want to exclude all numbers who start with 15 or less

so I can do something like:

```
WHERE TestColumn NOT LIKE '15%' AND TestColumn NOT LIKE '14%'
```

Is there a way to change this and use something like `TestColumn NOT LIKE < '15%'`

Comment: are you numbers integers or strings?

Comment: Why does `WHERE TestColumn >= 16000` not work?

Comment: @MartinSmith  there are numbers below 14000 that OP wants to grab

Comment: Why do you assume that? `I want to exclude all numbers who start with 15 or less`

Comment: @MartinSmith because his dataset includes numbers below 16000 and OP said I want all numbers that dont sart with 14/15

Comment: They didn't say that. I helpfully highlighted what they actually said above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the  value of TestColumn is  a string  you could use  a cast to integer of the two leftmost chars

```
    WHERE cast(left(TestColumn,2) as int) <=15
```

and for what in your comment

```
    WHERE cast(left(TestColumn,2) as int) <=15  
    and cast(lTestColumn as int) <>13093
```

Comment: and what if I want to do an exception I.Em exclude this number 13093 of where condition you provide?

Answer (score 0):

if your numbers are integers

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE TestColumn <= 14000 AND TestColumn >= 15999

SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE testColumn not between 14000 AND 15999
```

if your numbers are strings

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE TestColumn NOT LIKE '15%' AND TestColumn NOT LIKE '14%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first two characters are always digits, you can use:

```
where testcolumn >= '16'
```

This approach is nice because it can take advantage of an index.